# Maven Eclipse NoClassDefFoundError using Cloudant

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, noclassdeffounderror, cloudant

I have a Java project that is running on a local Liberty Server on eclipse. I am trying to use a Cloudant database.
If I run a test file using the database in the project as a Java Application, everything is fine, but when running the project on the Liberty Server, I get this error:

```
    `[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault:162'
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at [internal classes]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder
    at com.example.Testdb.createClient(Testdb.java:77)`
```

But the ClientBuilder is already added as a maven dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The .jar file is also included in the Java Build Path.
What can I do to eliminate the NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: Have you tried removing the <scope>provided</scope> option?

Comment: Yes, I changed the scope to `compile` and back to `provided` but either way I still get the same error

Comment: Hi. It sounds silly, but please try again to remove the 'provided' option and rebuild and run. That seems to be the obvious solution to me.  Also, here's a link that provides some useful instructions if you've not already seen it: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_couchdb_config.html.  There's a step there that instruct you to move the Cloudant .jar files into the `${server.config.dir}/lib` directory.